# AWX 9.1.1: j2 render Playbook runs successfully, but won't write results out to directory; running from CLI works properly

Tags: ansible-awx

I have a weird situation that I think is a bug in the latest release of AWX (v9.1.1). In fact, I have registered this issue as a possible bug with AWX development (Issue #5818). From the report:

SUMMARY

When executing a j2 template rendering Playbook role from AWX, the Playbook runs without error, but the rendered file is never written out to the directory. If you run the Playbook from the CLI, it runs without error and will write out the file correctly.

ENVIRONMENT

AWX version: 9.1.1

AWX install method: Docker Compose

Ansible version: AWX v2.8.5; CLI environment 2.9.4; have downgraded the CLI to 2.8.5 and no change in behavior.

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Web Browser: Chrome

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
Simply execute the Playbook role from CLI - successful. Execute within AWX - successful but no rendered template file is written.

EXPECTED RESULTS
Expect the template to render and show Change=1 as the completed status. Running the job once more should result in Change=0 due to idempotency.

ACTUAL RESULTS
No matter how many times the Playbook is ran in AWX, it still shows Change=1 (idempotency is indicating that the rendered file and existing file don't match).

--

One other piece of info noted during the debugs is that AWX 9.1.1 apparently uses Python3 in its venv; whereas my old functioning instance uses Python 2.7. Still, I've tried running the Playbook with different versions of Ansible and in both Python2 and Python3 venvs. Again, no issue with CLI execution with "ansible-playbook foo.yml".

Tried stopping all Containers, did a Docker system prune -a, deleted the cloned awx repo, and re-cloned/re-installed AWX. I've even tried pointing to both an internal and external assets database, but still no change.

Hopefully someone else has encountered this bizarre problem.

Thanks, Community!